# Show Google Map on the Top Half of the Android Screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

Currently I am showing Google Map in Android phone using Java on the whole screen which is working fine for me.

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Below is my XML file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0vAX8Xe9xjo5gkFNEEIH7KdHkNZNJWNnsjUPKkQ"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Problem Statement:-**

I need to show the Google Map on the Top Half of the Android Screen instead of showing on the full screen. And on the Bottom Half of the Screen I need to show TextBox. Is it possible to do this?

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, You need to give `height` as the `50%` of the screen!. add the `TextBox` field below the map and give the `layoutBelow` property to `TextBox`

Comment: Can you provide me the proper XML file, which I can use here? That will be great help to me.

Comment: @Nevzz03, sorry non my system right now! :-) I need to write XML if is it so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah its possible and can easily be implemented with `LinearLayout`. By assigning weight to `MapView` and `TextView`.

In this case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:apiKey="0vAX8Xe9xjo5gkFNEEIH7KdHkNZNJWNnsjUPKkQ"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: he can do this too by setting `layotBelow` on the `TextView` in the `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @HamzaWaqas agree but have to calculate screen size and assign to the map that why i wrote and can easily be implemented with LinearLayout.Thanks for the suggestion though.